# evitar registros repetidos (muchos a muchos) en mysql

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla Usuarios que se relaciona con una tabla Eventos, la relación es muchos a muchos, pues en un evento pueden haber varios usuarios y un usuario puede asistir a varios eventos.
Tengo creada la tabla intermediaria eventos_usuarios, con id_users e id_eventos.

El problema lo tengo en que hay registros repetidos, por ejemplo:
Tabla eventos_usuarios:

```
Id id_user id_event
1  1       1
2  1       2
3  1       1
4  2       1
5  2       2
```

El usuario 1, está en el evento 1 dos veces.

Como puedo evitar esta repetición?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Cual es tu consulta?, que haz intentado?

Comment: He intentado crear las tablas, con los campos, y concretamente en la de event_user, he indicado: foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade'). Lo mismo para 'event_id'. Pero no sé como evitar que un user_id y event_id coincida más de una vez en la tabla event_user. No sé si con 'unique' se soluciona, porque al ser id ya son valores únicos. Un user solo puede estar apuntado una vez a un mismo evento, y puede estar en varios eventos. Y un evento, solo puede tener un mismo usuario una vez, y puede tener varios usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero esta secuencia de instrucciones para eliminar los duplicados y después crear una clave única que evite nuevos duplicados:

```
ALTER TABLE eventos_usuarios ADD conservar bool;
UPDATE eventos_usuarios JOIN (
    SELECT id_user,id_event,
      MIN(Id) Id
      FROM eventos_usuarios
      GROUP BY 1,2
  ) c1 USING(Id,id_user,id_event)
  SET conservar=1;
DELETE FROM eventos_usuarios WHERE conservar IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE eventos_usuarios ADD UNIQUE(id_user,id_event);
ALTER TABLE eventos_usuarios DROP conservar;
```

Entiendo que partes de un dataset creado más o menos así:

```
CREATE TABLE eventos_usuarios(
  Id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_user int,
  id_event int
  );
INSERT INTO eventos_usuarios (Id, id_user, id_event) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 1),
(4, 2, 1),
(5, 2, 2);
```

Comment: Correcto el dataset es tal como has indicado. La solución que has pasado seguro que funciona, pero debo indicarlo en el archivo migrations de Laravel. De todas maneras, gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Finalmente lo he podido lograr, era más fácil de lo que pensaba. Este es el resultado:

```
        Schema::create('event_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('event_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            **$table->unique(array('user_id', 'event_Id'));**
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

La línea $table->unique(array('user_id', 'event_id')); es la que logra que no haya duplicados en ambas columnas.

Comment: Si tu pregunta es sobre base de datos (y se soluciona agregando distinct al query) que tiene que ver esta respuesta?